# How to run methods asynchronously with completable future

Tags: java, sql, asynchronous, completable-future

I am running a `Minecraft` server and I am creating a plugin that when the players execute a certain command. It gets the amount of 'coins' they have in a `sql` database. However I am running into trouble using `CompletableFuture` to run my SQL methods asynchronously. My `CoinUsable` class keeps on blocking and my main and sql class too. I am very new to asynchronous programming.

I just need to figure out a way to run my Methods in my `CoinUsable` and `SQLManager` class asynchronously.

My main class where the player executes the command.

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> cf = CoinUsable.getPlayerCoins(player);
                        cf.thenAcceptAsync((value) -> {
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "You own " + ChatColor.GOLD + value + ChatColor.GRAY + " coins");
                        });
```

My CoinUsable/Manager class

```
public CompletableFuture<Integer> getPlayerCoins(Player p) {
           return SQL.getPlayerBits(p);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> addPlayerBits(Player p, int bitAmount) {
            SQL.addBits(p, bitAmount);
            return null;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> removePlayerBits(Player p, int bitAmount) {
            SQL.removeBits(p, bitAmount);
            return null;
    }
```

My SQLManager class

```
public CompletableFuture<Integer> getPlayerBits(Player p) {
        String queryStr = "SELECT Coins FROM PlayerData WHERE PlayerUID=?";
        try {
            Connection conn = getConn();
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
            st.setString(1, p.getUniqueId().toString());
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            Integer amount = (Integer) rs.getInt("Coins");
            conn.close();
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(amount);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> addBits(Player p, int bitAmount) {
        String queryStr = "UPDATE PlayerData SET Coins = Coins + ? WHERE PlayerUID=?";
        try {
            Connection conn = getConn();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
            ps.setInt(1, bitAmount);
            ps.setString(2, p.getUniqueId().toString());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> removeBits(Player p, int bitAmount) {
        String queryStr = "UPDATE PlayerData SET Coins = Coins - ? WHERE PlayerUID=?";
        try {
            Connection conn = getConn();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
            ps.setInt(1, bitAmount);
            ps.setString(2, p.getUniqueId().toString());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
}
```

My main class is blocking, which is causing the whole server to lagg. Also my CoinUsable class it blocking too, which means a player has to wait for another players request to go through before he can send his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Runnable runnable)`

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() after it runs the given action.

And `CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier)`

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() with the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.

For asynchronous execution use `supplyAsync` and `runAsync`, the way you are using `CompletableFuture` is wrong

**CoinUsable/Manager class :** Use `supplyAsync` and `runAsync` methods to call the `SQLManager` class methods, so that `getPlayerBits`, `addBits` and `removeBits` will get executed asynchronously

```
public CompletableFuture<Integer> getPlayerCoins(Player p) {
       return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->SQL.getPlayerBits(p));
}

public CompletableFuture<Void> addPlayerBits(Player p, int bitAmount) {
       return CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->SQL.addBits(p, bitAmount));

}

public CompletableFuture<Void> removePlayerBits(Player p, int bitAmount) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->SQL.removeBits(p, bitAmount));

}
```

**My SQLManager class :** In `SQLManager` class just keep methods with normal with respective return types

```
public Integer getPlayerBits(Player p) {
    String queryStr = "SELECT Coins FROM PlayerData WHERE PlayerUID=?";
    try {
        Connection conn = getConn();
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
        st.setString(1, p.getUniqueId().toString());
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        Integer amount = (Integer) rs.getInt("Coins");
        conn.close();
        return amount;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void addBits(Player p, int bitAmount) {
    String queryStr = "UPDATE PlayerData SET Coins = Coins + ? WHERE PlayerUID=?";
    try {
        Connection conn = getConn();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
        ps.setInt(1, bitAmount);
        ps.setString(2, p.getUniqueId().toString());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void removeBits(Player p, int bitAmount) {
    String queryStr = "UPDATE PlayerData SET Coins = Coins - ? WHERE PlayerUID=?";
    try {
        Connection conn = getConn();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
        ps.setInt(1, bitAmount);
        ps.setString(2, p.getUniqueId().toString());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }
 }
```